# How do I setup new compilation symbols in a MVC application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation, debug-symbols

[image]Here's my setup for compilation for Release and debug.
What if I want to create a compilation build for client called "clientX" and "ClientY".

So I need a setup for ClientX.Debug, ClientX.Release and ClientY.Debug, ClientY.Release.
How do I setup these symbols in visual studio 2010? In order for #if (ClientX.Debug) to work?

Extension code to check for release build:

```
public static bool IsReleaseBuild(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
#if DEBUG
    return false;
#else
    return true;
#endif
}
```

How this is used for any view (razor syntax):

```
@if(Html.IsReleaseBuild())
```

***** Update I made the following changes:******

Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
Click the Configuration Properties folder.
Click the Build property page.
Modify the Conditional Compilation Constants property.

I created the following: AMS_Debug, AMS_Release, GM_Release and GM_Debug

I added the following code in the layout pages:

```
@{

    #if (AMS_Debug) 
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AMSLayout.cshtml";
    #else
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GMLayout.cshtml";
    #endif       
}
```

For some reason, it never hits AMS_Debug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436369/how-to-define-a-constant-globally-in-c-sharp-like-debug

Comment: Just followed the steps, not sure why my constants are not being picked up?

Comment: Updated my question to reflect changes